# Do not offer to ask if answers already exits

Tags: feature-request, localization, cross-posting, russian-stackoverflow

This question [How to convert int to QString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211771/how-to-convert-int-to-qstring) on Stack Overflow (in English) has cross-site duplicate on Stack Overflow in Russian. According to [cross-site association technique](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4500/176217) I as a Russian-speaking user see two banners:

> [image: banners]

The top one says:

> There are answers for such question on Stack Overflow in Russian: {Question title}

The bottom says:

> Not found an answer? Ask a question on Stack Overflow in Russian.

I think that in purpose of preventing duplicates (on ruSO) the last banner should be removed from the page. There is no reason to ask if answers already exist.