# Allow non-English sites to exist in Hot Network Question list based on browser accepted languages

Tags: feature-request, hot-questions, localization

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/325546/339911) (and a comment) all non-English sites are excluded from the HNQ list. In the same time when browser accepted-languages contains a non-English language you can see in some cases on Stack Overflow [the banner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/311016/339911) which displays you a link to International SO of that non-English language.

I suggest using this technique to allow to include (and display) for such users question from the localized sites in Hot Network Question list. This will improve introduction of non-English sites into SE Network without harming only English speaking people.

Comment: This might be too complex to implement. I'd suggest an alternative by a single switch that filters out non-English, so ES/PT/RU/JA would show up or be filtered out together, not separately.

Comment: @ɪBᴜɢ filtering all the languages together is not good solution. For instance I know Russian, but Japanese looks for me like a うどんプレート.

Comment: Whatever that answer and comment says sites dedicated to non-English languages do appear although the non-English versions of Stack Overflow do not. Spanish Language appeared quite recently.

Comment: It's all ελληνικά to me.

Comment: Why not just put all hot question together? Even when I'm using the Spanish site, I get bombarded with "guiri" questions all the time and I don't complain about it